# Scheduled restarts for a CloudFoundry service (or, using the cf-cli from a scheduled job)

Tags: cloud-foundry, vmware, job-scheduling

I'm trying to use the [Scheduler](https://docs.vmware.com/en/Scheduler-for-VMware-Tanzu/1.6/scheduler-vmware-tanzu/GUID-using-jobs.html) to schedule weekly restarts of my application.

I've done the following:

```bash
cf create-service scheduler-for-pcf standard my-scheduler
cf bind-service my-app my-scheduler
cf create-job my-app my-job "cf restart my-app"
cf schedule-job my-job "0 0 ? * 1 "
```

All of these commands execute successfully.

But when the scheduled job starts, `cf restart my-app` fails with `cf: command not found`. Surprisingly, the CloudFoundry CLI is not available by default in CloudFoundry jobs.

Is there a way that I can install the cf cli on a job? Or, is there some other way to schedule restarts? Seems like it would be such a common use case.